# Introduce information in a form from Database and show it c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working with **form** and I would like to introduce like a table where I can select differents options.
And example would be this:

[image: Example of form]

In this picture, there are two attributes, *Código* and *Nombre*. I get this information from a *database*. My problem is that I don't know how can I put all that information (*Código* and *Nombre*) in the middle of the form and then give the option to choose one.

My `InitializeComponent` is the following:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.btnCancelar = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // button3
    // 
    this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 226);
    this.button3.Name = "button3";
    this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button3.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button3.Text = "button3";
    this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
    // 
    // Cancelar
    // 
    this.btnCancelar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 226);
    this.btnCancelar.Name = "btnCancelar";
    this.btnCancelar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.btnCancelar.TabIndex = 1;
    this.btnCancelar.Text = "&Cancelar";
    this.btnCancelar.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.btnCancelar.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnCancelar_Click);
    // 
    // FormEmpresas
    // 
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
    this.Controls.Add(this.btnCancelar);
    this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
    this.Name = "FormEmpresas";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

Comment: Use `ListView`.

Comment: Do you mean a dropdown list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not modify InitializeComponents. The Designer works on one part - this function. You work on another part - the one with constructor. If you modify the Designer part, you will just get the GUI or Compilzer seizing up because you changed the Designer part. Change your part and only your part.

Getting the Information is a simple [SQL Select](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp). Make sure you retrieve (but do not nessesarily show) the primary key. Such a UI is usually about getting the Primary Key for further Queries from the user, without nessesarily telling him about the Key (the user is mostly intersted on all the other rows of that Table).

Such a query should be started *earliest* in the Shown() or Activated() events for the form. Ealier is prone to cause issues with stuff not being properly there yet. Also ideally this query should involve some Async processing down the line. DB Queries are notorious for be long running operations and long running + GUI do not mix so well. But for simple test, the non-async way works well.

General Design notes: This looks like a Modal OK/Cancel Dialog with a single ListView Element. Modal Dialogs are just Forms shown with ShowDialog().

Answer (score 3):

I believe that [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) should be enough. There's plenty of examples and tutorials, starting with [MSDN one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x64c23x.aspx) through [some tips](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33748/0/page/1) related to the control and finally more complex examples (not necessarily for DGV only) with [data binding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/databinding_tutorial.aspx).